# 3D Куб. Как сделать вращения плавными?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, html5, css-animation

При нажатии на стрелочки куб начинает вращаться. 
Когда свойство transition стоит где то до 0.1s то при удержании клавиши куб вращается нормально без рывков и прочего. Но нужно сделать это вращение плавным. Тут получается, что если удержать клавишу, то каждый раз функция вызывается по новой, и перекрывает предыдущую, как бы обрезая время анимации.  Для плавности нужно ждать окончания анимации. Как сделать плавно и без рывков?
Вот куб:

```js
var coord = [0, 0];    // left - right, up - down;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function () {
    var coub = document.getElementsByClassName('coub')[0];
    if(event.keyCode == 37){    //      left
        coord[0] -= 10;
        coub.style.transform = 'rotateY(' + coord[0] + 'deg)' + 'rotateZ(' + coord[1] + 'deg)';
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 39){    //  right
        coord[0] += 10;
        coub.style.transform = 'rotateY(' + coord[0] + 'deg)' + 'rotateZ(' + coord[1] + 'deg)';
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 38){    //      up
        coord[1] -= 10;
        coub.style.transform = 'rotateY(' + coord[0] + 'deg)' + 'rotateZ(' + coord[1] + 'deg)';
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 40){    //      down
        coord[1] += 10;
        coub.style.transform = 'rotateY(' + coord[0] + 'deg)' + 'rotateZ(' + coord[1] + 'deg)';
    }
})
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.contain{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.coub{
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 1s;
}
.side{
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid;
    font-size: 40px;
}
.front{
    transform: translateZ(100px);
    background-color: rgba(204, 231, 204, 0.3);
}
.back{
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(100px);
    background-color: rgba(191, 86, 0, 0.3);
}
.left{
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
    background-color: rgba(43, 53, 187, 0.3);
}
.right{
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
    background-color: rgba(176, 207, 0, 0.3);
}
.top{
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
    background-color: rgba(50, 177, 170, 0.3);
}
.bottom{
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
    background-color: rgb(160, 20, 20, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
        <div class="coub">
            <div class="side front">front</div>
            <div class="side back">back</div>
            <div class="side left">left</div>
            <div class="side right">right</div>
            <div class="side top">top</div>
            <div class="side bottom">bottom</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: можно через requestAnimationFrame и чуть более сложный код js

Answer (score 2):

Можно через `requestAnimationFrame` и чуть более сложный код js:

```js
let angles = [0, 0];
let dir = [0, 0];
let coub = document.getElementsByClassName('coub')[0];
 
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 37) 
    dir[0] = -1;
  if (event.keyCode === 39) 
    dir[0] =  1;
  if (event.keyCode === 38) 
    dir[1] = -1;
  if (event.keyCode === 40) 
    dir[1] =  1;
})

document.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 37 || event.keyCode === 39) 
    dir[0] = 0;
  if (event.keyCode === 38 || event.keyCode === 40) 
    dir[1] = 0;
})

requestAnimationFrame(apply)

function apply() {
  requestAnimationFrame(apply)
  coub.style.transform = 
      'rotateY(' + (angles[0] += dir[0]) + 'deg)' + 
      'rotateZ(' + (angles[1] += dir[1]) + 'deg)';
}
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.contain{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    perspective: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.coub{
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.side{
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid;
    font-size: 40px;
}
.front{
    transform: translateZ(100px);
    background-color: rgba(204, 231, 204, 0.3);
}
.back{
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(100px);
    background-color: rgba(191, 86, 0, 0.3);
}
.left{
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
    background-color: rgba(43, 53, 187, 0.3);
}
.right{
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
    background-color: rgba(176, 207, 0, 0.3);
}
.top{
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
    background-color: rgba(50, 177, 170, 0.3);
}
.bottom{
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
    background-color: rgb(160, 20, 20, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
    <div class="coub">
        <div class="side front">front</div>
        <div class="side back">back</div>
        <div class="side left">left</div>
        <div class="side right">right</div>
        <div class="side top">top</div>
        <div class="side bottom">bottom</div>
    </div>
</div>
```